# 50+ reopen votes under Review?

Tags: discussion, review

Recently a huge amount of reopen votes appeared under the **review** tab, 53 to be exact. Some of these were closed as duplicates, e.g.

1. [Copying Greek text from notebooks as unicode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6263/89)
2. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11256/lost-solution-of-the-equation
3. [A Faster way to combine two Lists of different structures into one of a different structure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20698/a-faster-way-to-combine-two-lists-of-different-structures-into-one-of-a-differen)

Since usually there are only a few, I was surprised about it. The review page does not help much why or by whom these are pushed now to the review queue. The only info is: "*This question was edited after it was closed. Should it be reopened?*" Is the mass-appearance of such reopen votes normal (e.g. every month community robots randomly push closed posts for reopen) or was it initiated by a moderator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the MSO question that explains this: [Lots of questions in the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078)

---

It is my understanding that at present new edit causes a closed question to be added to the reopen review queue.  This does not normally apply to Duplicate questions as distinct from Closed questions under the new system.  However, in this case it appears that the new logic has been retroactively applied to the "old" type of duplicate questions that were a subtype of Closed.  No, it was not initiated by a community moderator.

After starting to review some of these I see it is both the old and new Duplicates, ans well as other types of Closed questions.

Comment: Thanks, that explains. Next time I try not to forget to check the SO.meta for info! And the final word is that we should evaluate these as before.